# Need help with this "if" statement in Objective-C, how to display?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, if-statement

I'm trying to display all the objects in this array (prefixes) with the variable `sufField` in a list.

```
    if (newsPre.on = YES)
    {
        NSArray *newsArray = [NSArray AarrayWithObjects = @"News", @"Latest", @"Trending", nil;]
        for(int i=0, i<3, ++i;)
        {
            NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sufField, newsArray objectAtIndex: i];
            display.text=newText;
        }

    }
```

For example if sufField = "channel" the desired output would be...

```
Newschannel
Latestchannel
Trendingchannel
```

I'm getting a variety of build errors such as "Expected ']' before '=' token" in the NSArray line..... and others dealing with the "for" statement.

Please help! thanks!

Comment: You're getting build errors because your code is not valid Objective-C. First, learn the syntax of the language. *Then* write code with it.

Comment: I echo Jonathan's thoughts, seriously. On another note, this isn't about Xcode (so I've removed that from your title); moreover, it _really_ is **Xcode** and not **xCode**, for future reference. When I first learned Objective-C, I found [Scott Stevenson's guide](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/) to be of the greatest value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh man...

```
if (newsPre.on = YES) {
```

You need two equal signs there.  Otherwise you're invoking a setter method.  (See? Dot syntax is bad!)  As it currently stands, this is saying:  `if ([newsPre setOn:YES]) {`.  What you want is either `newsPre.on == YES` or `[newsPre on] == YES`.

```
    NSArray *newsArray = [NSArray AarrayWithObjects = @"News", @"Latest", @"Trending", nil;]
```

First, the semicolon goes *after* the bracket.  It's supposed to be the last thing on the line.  Also, "AarrayWithObjects" should be "arrayWithObjects", and that extra "=" in the middle of the line should be ":".

```
    for(int i=0, i<3, ++i;) {
```

Those commas are supposed to be semi colons

```
        NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sufField, newsArray objectAtIndex: i];
```

You only have one substitution modifier (`%@`), but you're trying to substitute in 2 values.  Additionally, you need brackets around "`newsArray objectAtIndex:i`"

```
        display.text=newText;
```

Hooray!  A syntactically correct line!  However, this is happening on *every* iteration of the loop.  So every time you loop, you're changing the text of `display`. Are you sure that's what you want?

```
    }
```

This is OK

```
}
```

This is OK too.

In summary: learn the syntax.

Comment: Well I've had all those fixes already, and it builds, excellent! But now I'm getting a strange error in the "display" UITextView which is what I'm using for output. (see the link in my comment above) all the code is correct (builds no errors or warnings), so I'm guessing this could be a problem in Xcode.

Comment: Actually I shouldn't call it an error, it's just not a string or what I expected. And also the link for the output screenshot is below not above...

Comment: @Ktmock13 the reason you're getting that "<UITextField: 0x6915650" stuff in your text field is likely because `sufField` is a `UITextField`, and you're writing its description into a string, and then showing that string in the UI.  Perhaps you want `[sufField text]` instead?

Comment: Yep that fixed it, thanks a lot for your patients and help Dave! I appreciate it!

Comment: @Dave Delong, You got it. I also took into consideration what you said about the display.text changing every time it loops. What I need to happen is for it to print each iteration of the loop... i've been playing with stringByAppendingString but sadly no luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

You should be using semicolons — not commas — to separate the three components of a `for` loop.

Your `NSArray` problem is probably because you have the semicolon statement terminator on the wrong side of the closing bracket and your message sending syntax is wrong; this:

```
[NSArray AarrayWithObjects = @"News", @"Latest", @"Trending", nil;]
```

should probably be:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"News", @"Latest", @"Trending", nil];
```

as you are sending the `arrayWithObjects` message to the `NSArray` class.

Comment: I fixed what you said, and here's a screenshot of  the remaining build errors... http://tinypic.com/r/28vpqf7/7

Comment: @Ktmock13: You still have an '=' rather than ':' after `arrayWithObjects`; and you only need two semicolons in the `for`. Also have a look at what anon says about the `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (newsPre.on == YES)
{
    NSArray *newsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"News", @"Latest", @"Trending", nil];
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sufField, [newsArray objectAtIndex: i]];
        display.text=newText;
    }

}
```

This should work.

Mr. Mu forgot that newsArray objectAtIndex: i should have brackets, your string w/ format is similar to a printf statement: therefore you need tags for both objects.

Comment: @mu is too short: Oops my bad missed that... been a while since I've done standard iPhone programming xD. Thanks for catching the mistake.

Comment: Great help guys! The code is sound in xcode with no build errors. However, instead of my desired output i'm getting some strange output like this http://tinypic.com/r/6tpw7l/7

Comment: This still has issues.  you need two equal signs in the if statement.

Comment: Johnathan Sterling brought up a good point ^ does my code follow objective-c syntax? If not could this be why i'm getting strange output?  If my code weren't in Obj-C format I would assume Xcode, which  is designed to read  Obj-C syntax, would recognize this and return an error... but it doesn't.

Comment: @Ktmock: Just because Xcode doesn't give you errors it doesn't mean you are not doing something wrong. I don't see anything wrong with the code I have posted, I would check elsewhere for the issue.